# Ubuntu isn't detecting M.2 SSD, but the BIOS does

Tags: 20.04, ssd, m2

I currently use Ubuntu 20.04.3, but my M.2 SSD isn't being detected by Ubuntu.

My system:
Ryzen 7 2700,
Asus Ex-a320m gaming,
ADATA SU650 120gb

I've disabled fast boot, secure boot, and SATA AHCI mode.

My SSD is new, I've encountered this problem before so I replaced the SSD with a new one and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Many need UEFI update & SSD firmware update. What brand SSD? I downloaded Samsung update ISO for my NVMe SSD and created a bootable update. It looked like an old DOS screen and only had my model as an update. If you are dual booting with Windows you often can update easier.

Comment: Gparted deos not show ive tried

Comment: @oldfred ive just updated bios and nothing change

Comment: @Robert lspci i dont see ssd in this command all i see is AMD controller ETC

Comment: Is the disk system set to AHCI mode, or RAID/RST mode, in the BIOS?

Comment: Use `sudo journalctl --since="-5 minutes"` within 4 minutes of inserting the SSD to see what's going on.

Comment: The sentence *I've disabled* (...) *SATA AHCI mode* suggests you did the opposite of what you should have and that alone would explain the SSD not being recognized. You need to enable AHCI, the other modes aren't (yet) compatible.